# How to prove that the set given by $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ is connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I seem to be stuck on. I think I figured out how to show $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is connected I believe. If $X$ is connected and $f:X \to  Y$ is continuous, then $f(x)$ is connected. By setting  $X=[0, 2\Pi]$, and $f$ as the function $(\cos x, \sin x)$, then $f(X)$ is the image of the function in that domain so it must be connected. However, I can't seem to figure it out with 3 variables.

Edit: $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$

Comment: The sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is clearly path connected (you might want to show this), hence it is connected.

Comment: Was that last $x^2$ in the title supposed to be a $z^2$?

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the reply. I'm new to this unit and I can see that it would be connected. But I'm stuck on the proof. In class they provided us with the definition that S is path connected if for every two points a,b there exists a path f: [0,1] st f[0] = a and f[1] = b. Should I approach it by getting two arbitrary points and showing that they are connected then.

Comment: Yes $z^2$. My bad

Answer (score 4):

A similar argument works. The function
$$f:[0,2\pi]\times[0,2\pi]\to S^2$$
given by 
$$(u,v)\mapsto (\cos u \cos v,\cos u \sin v, \sin u)$$
is continuous onto $S^2$ and since squares are connected, the sphere is, too.

You might want to restrict the domain, but for the purposes of your argument it works this way.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the reply. Yeah it just all clicked. Seems like a dumb question in retrospect but I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Don't worry. Sometimes it happens.